# Difference b/w thread.sleep and sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER.sleep(duration)?

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium and understood that why we should not use the thread.sleep [better option is wait.until(ExpectedConditions..) ]

I am trying to hand the alerts and want to wait until it pops up....

Can anyone please clear the difference between thread.sleep and sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER.sleep(duration)??

if thread.sleep slows down the automation, is it same with sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER??

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used sleeper module, but thread.sleep only slows your application as much as you sleep. What you may want to do is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as Condition
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

# Start your driver
driver = ...
# Then wherever you want to wait for an alert
timeout = 10    # Max time to wait in seconds
try:
    # This waits only as long as needed to detect the alert, then continues.
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(Condition.alert_is_present())
    print("Alert was found, now what?")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout waiting for alert")
```